# JSF p:inputText is not coming in ManagedBean while file upload listener is called

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am using **JSF 2.2.20**. In the xhtml page, there is one input text field and a file upload (advanced mode) . But my problem is, while listener is called for file-upload, the input text is coming as empty. How can I get the input text? Help me out.

xhtml code snippet:

```
    <h:form id="formID" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <p:growl id="growlId" sticky="true" showDetail="true"><p:autoUpdate /></p:growl>
        
        <p:outputPanel id="DocInfo">
            <h:panelGrid id="DocGrid" columns="3" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="8">
                
                <p:outputLabel for="upload_Doc_Name" value="Document Name :* " />
                <p:inputText id="upload_Doc_Name" value="#{uploadDocManagedBean.uploadDocName}"  style="font-size:8pt;width:230px" />
                    
                <p:outputLabel for="projectUploadDocId" value="Choose File :* " style="font-weight:bold; float:left" />
                <p:fileUpload id="projectUploadDocId"  value="#{uploadDocManagedBean.uploadedFile}"  mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true" 
                        listener="#{uploadDocManagedBean.fileUploadListener}"  />
                
                <br/>
                
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:outputPanel>
   </h:form>
```

The managed bean code snippet:

```
    @ManagedBean(name = "uploadDocManagedBean")
        @ViewScoped
        public class UploadDocManagedBean implements Serializable {
        
       private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

        private String uploadDocName;
        private UploadedFile uploadedFile;
        public String getUploadDocName() {
                return uploadDocName;
        }
        
        public void setUploadDocName(String uploadDocName) {
            this.uploadDocName = uploadDocName;
        }
        public UploadedFile getUploadedFile() {
            return uploadedFile;
        }

        public void setUploadedFile(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
            this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
        }
        
        public void fileUploadListener(FileUploadEvent fileUploadEvent) {
                try {
                    uploadedFile = fileUploadEvent.getFile();
                    String filename = uploadedFile.getFileName();
                    
                    if (uploadDocName == null || uploadDocName.isEmpty()) {
                        String msg = "Document Name is empty.";
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("growlId",
                                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, msg, msg));
                        return;
        
                    } 
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
```

In the managed bean, the `uploadDocName` is the coming as empty everytime, while this `fileUploadListener()` method is called.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you please put some code for understanding?

Comment: I tried this one , but it did not work. `uploadDocName` is still coming empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `process` attribute on `fileUpload`. To make it simple, try with `process="@form"`, it should work ;) By default, only `fileUpload` client id e.g `@this` is sent to the server for processing

More details for fileUpload component, see here: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/components/fileupload

Comment: I tried this one, you know. But didn't work for me. :(

Comment: I see... behaviors are decoded before process components. Then I would suggest using an ajax event (e.g blur, change) on inputText, so your filename setter gets called before your listener